# Salesforce: Build report and chart for average daily calls by user

Tags: salesforce, report, average, formula

I need to build a dashboard chart based on a report that shows the average number of calls made daily by my sales team for 7 trailing days.  Also, cannot use fixed number (7) as part of the formula, since weekends and days off will throw off the average.  Want to show each of my 5 guys' average in one bar chart.

(Im)patiently waiting for Tier 2 Salesforce support to get back to me since yesterday....

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an average on daily basis why do you care about weekends. They'll show up empty or will not show at all if you use grouping in a report therefore any charts will not include them and will only have 5 groups for the last 5 work days.